# Getting stock with demandware/cloud commerce OCAPI

Tags: demandware

How would I get the stock of an item via the demandware/cloud commerce OCAPI?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the following OCAPI:

```
GET /inventory_lists/{inventory_list_id}/product_inventory_records/{product_id}
```

Answer (score 1):

see below example which assumes that you have a valid token.

```
GET {{shop_url}}/products/701644676568M/availability
```